# How can I apply to functions to a list in haskell?

Tags: list, haskell, palindrome

I'm trying to write a function that checks whether or not a given list is a palindrome. However, I can't figure out how to apply to functions to a given input.
My Code looks like this:

```
isPalindrome :: [a] -> Bool
isPalindrome x
  | head x == last x = True
  | otherwise = isPalindrome tail (init x)
```

This doesn't work and I cant figure out why.

Comment: syntactically, you meant `isPalindrome (tail (init x))`, with the extra pair of parentheses.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The main problem with the code is the logic - it is saying "if the head and tails match, it is a palindrome, accept.  Otherwise..."  The real test is "if the head and tail differ, reject.  Otherwise check the center part."

Answer (score 0):

**You have to think in the cases, this function does the trick:**

```
isPalindrome []       = True   
isPalindrome [x]      = True   
isPalindrome [x,y]    = x == y 
isPalindrome xs       = (head xs) == (last xs) && isPalindrome ((tail . init) xs)
```

With an example:

```
isPalindrome "aabaa"  -->
isPalindrome "aabaa"   = (head "aabaa") == (last "aabaa") && isPalindrome ((tail . init) "aabaa")
```

next step)

```
isPalindrome "aabaa"  = ('a') == ('a') && isPalindrome "aba"
```

next step) `isPalindrome "aba"`

```
(head "aba") == (last "aba") && isPalindrome ((tail . init) "aba")
```

next step ->

```
('a') == ('a') && isPalindrome "b")
```

last step ->

```
isPalindrome "b"
isPalindrome [x]      = True
```

so we have the expression:

```
 ('a') == ('a') && ('a') == ('a') && True --> True
```

Comment: Thank you, however this still doesn't seem to work. When I tried out your code, I got the Compiler Error: ``` 99probs.hs:27:27: error:
    * No instance for (Eq a) arising from a use of `=='
      Possible fix:
        add (Eq a) to the context of
          the type signature for:
            isPalindrome :: forall a. [a] -> Bool
    * In the expression: x == y
      In an equation for `isPalindrome': isPalindrome [x, y] = x == y
27 | isPalindrome [x,y]    = x == y
   ´´´ Can you explain to me, why that happens? Do I need to add an EQ Typeclass or something?

Comment: Just don’t add the type to the equation and Haskell will infer it for you

Comment: What I was saying is don't add this type `isPalindrome :: [a] -> Bool` let haskell infer it for you, try not to adding that line and it will compile